# How to fix "AuthorizationHeaderMalformed when calling the GetObject operation" error in AWS s3 boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

When I try to run very simple Python script to get object from s3 bucket:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
 region_name="eu-east-1",
 verify=False,
 aws_access_key_id="QxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFY=",
 aws_secret_access_key="c1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxYw==")

obj = s3.Object('3gxxxxxxxxxxs7', 'dk5xxxxxxxxxxn94')
result = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')

print(result)
```

I got an error:

```
$ python3 script.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 7, in <module>
    result = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: 

An error occurred (AuthorizationHeaderMalformed) 
when calling the GetObject operation:
 The authorization header is malformed; the authorization component 
"Credential=QUtJxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxlZPUFY=/20191005/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request" 
is malformed.
```

I'm not sure what can be causing it, worth adding that:

- I don't know what is the bucket region (don't ask why) but I tried manually to connect to all of them (by changing default region name in command to every region) and without success.
- I don't have access to bucket configuration. And anything that is in aws console. I just have the Key ID, Secret, bucket name and object name.

Comment: Your key seems wrong , please check.

Comment: Often the reason of this error is something wrong with credentials, of course I added 'xxx' to not make them public.

Comment: I never have seen the access key has `=`  but I am not sure.

Comment: In my case, I just swap the variables (`access` & `secret`). So make to sure to use the correct ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An AWS-Access-Key-ID *always* begins with `AKIA` for IAM users or `ASIA` for temporary credentials from Security Token Service, as noted in [IAM Identifiers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html) in the *AWS Identity and Access Management User Guide*.

The value you're using does not appear to be one of these, since it starts with `QUtJ`... so this it isn't the value you should be using here.  You appear to be using something that isn't an AWS-Access-Key-ID.

Answer (score 3):

Not long time ago I had similar problem because I am 90% sure it a task from recruitment interview ;)
For all future travelers trying to recruit to this company: this credentials are encrypted, unfortunetly I forgot encryption type but surely a very common one.